# Break text that covers other views

Tags: ios, uitextview, swift3

Is it possible to break the text automatically, so the text isn't covering it, like the example below, in UITextview?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `CoreText` Framework

```
import CoreText
```

Add the below code after adding the `imageView` to `UITextView`,

```
var exclusionPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: imageView.frame.orgin.x, y: imageView.frame.orgin.y, width: imageView.frame.size.width, height: imageView.frame.size.height))
textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [exclusionPath]
textView.addSubview(imageView)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping` meaning that the word'll be cut after a character.

```
textview.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
```

Comment: The problem isn't the line breaking, but that it covers the image :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do exactly the design like this way. Although I have not used Swift 3, but you can format it accordingly to the syntax.

Here the `exclusionPath` will be responsible for starting the text after image and `exclusionPath1` to start the text below image, as per your requirement.

**My Code :**

```
    let txtView = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 64, SCREEN_SIZE.width, 150));
    self.view.addSubview(txtView);

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50));
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "icon");

    let exclusionPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height));
    let exclusionPath1 = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(-50, 50, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height));

    txtView.textContainer.exclusionPaths  = [exclusionPath, exclusionPath1];
    txtView.addSubview(imageView);
```

**Output :**

[image]

Hope it helps

Happy coding ...